# Lubuntu 16.04/18.04 - Failed to install boot loader

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

I have been installing ubuntu in VMs (using KVM) for development for quite some time now and I have been facing a problem where the boot loader never seemed to install and just fail.

So, either I would install the boot loader manually or just manually partition the disk while installing.

What's the best fix for a smoother install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `virt-manager` (or GNOME Boxes) instead of directly using the `kvm` / `qemu -kvm` command.  You will hopefully find that 1) the creation wizard attempts to autodetect the distribution & version of the install media; 2) if it fails to auto-detect, you will be offered a list which includes recent versions of Ubuntu.  (I.e., if your Ubuntu version is too new to be listed in your virt-manager, you can usually just select the most recent Ubuntu version from the list.  But see NOTE below in any case).

The implication is that `virt-manager` chooses an efficient "hardware" configuration, which meets the hardware requirements of Ubuntu, and provides the most efficient virtual hardware that Ubuntu is able to use.

NOTE.  `virt-manager` also offers an option to expand this configuration, i.e. customize the hardware config before starting the install.  Personally, I make sure to do this and and double-check the RAM size against the Ubuntu installation documents.  I had to increase RAM size at one point to avoid the VM grinding to a halt somewhere during the install, I think this was with Ubuntu 18.04 but I might be mis-remembering.

I have successfully installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 <del>and 18.04</del>[*] from their respective live cds, using this method.  (I *think* they do not default to LVM, but I tend to avoid enabling LVM inside VMs.  Some of the uses of LVM may be met by [instead creating and resizing separate virtual disks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445583/29483)).

(If either Ubuntu enabled LVM by default for you, or you have a specific reason for wanting LVM services inside a VM, perhaps you could edit your question to be more specific).

[*] um.  actually I forgot, something did go wrong with installing Ubuntu Destop 18.04 from the live cd, running inside virt-manager on Fedora Linux 28.  The installer GUI stopped updating, and I think there was a kernel hung task message about QXL.  Changing the type of virtual graphics hardware avoided this, I think I used Cirrus.  It might be possible to change the graphics hardware back after finishing the install and applying all software updates including the kernel.

Comment: I do use `virt-manager` but I guess I kinda reused boxes which I used for CentOS or something else. That is probably why I got that error. I just tried a new VM from scratch and it worked! And about LVM, I guess I just went with it by habit. Like in the other answer, I just use separate disks for data anyways, so there is no benefit of LVM here then. Thanks!

Comment: @PramodhValavala unlucky :). I did wonder if you were passing a disk image with some pre-created partition table. Btw I have updated this answer because I just remembered I *did* have a specific problem with 18.04, so I don't want to give a misleading impression about that :).  I don't remember having the same problem with 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution to this problem of mine.

The virtual drives were using msdos partition tables which was causing problems if I let the ubuntu installer set up the LVM partitions for me.

But when I changed the partition table to `gpt` (using gparted), the install went through fine.

Comment: something is not well explained here, people have been using LVM for ages with both setups.

Comment: I guess the problem is not exactly pertaining to lvm but how the Ubuntu installer sets things up. I have come across many questions similar to this but never found a solution to it until now and wanted to share this.